# How do I use the Object Detection API to evaulate an own custom model? What do I write into the config files?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have a custom object detection model that I can call with `model = MyModel()` and `model.loadweights(checkpoint)` and I want to evaluate it using the Object Detection API.

From what I understood there are two possibilities, either I use the legacy eval.py, there I don't know, what to put into the pipeline_config file

Or I use the newer version that is implemented in model_main_tf2.py, but there I would have to save my model as model.config and I don't know what to put the pipeline file either.

Since my model is a YOLO model, it is not included in the sample once yet.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/configs/tf2

Would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't calculate the mAP using the Object Detection API because there's no `pipeline.config` file for Yolo.

However, you can check [this](https://github.com/YunYang1994/tensorflow-yolov3#22-evaluate-on-voc-dataset) repo out. It's a Tensorflow based implementation of YoloV3. They have working code for calculating mAP. You can modify this accordingly to calculate the mAP of your model.

Comment: Oh I thought one is actually supposed to write a file themself, but thanks nevertheless.

Comment: If the answer helped you out, please consider marking it as accepted and upvoting it by clicking the up arrow icon

Comment: I tried and it won't show because I am a new user and therefor have to low reputation.